# Mule SFTP component

Tags: mule, mule-component

Hi I have below queries with SFTP component if you guys can help me out that would be a great help:

1) Can we get the file size of the file picked up by SFTP component? I need to restrict the transfer based on the size of file.
2) Can I get the number of files and the file names picked up by the SFTP component?
3) Is the understanding correct: SFTP component picks up all the files from the server and keep in memory and do the processing 1 by 1 until it finishes all files?
4) If server has 5 files can SFTP component process all the 5 files in parallel rather than 1 by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Mule does not populate the file-size field for SFTP as they do with FILE.  There are Jira tickets open on this matter but MuleSoft has called it an enhancement and not given it a priority.  I disagree.  Perhaps ping MuleSoft, if enough users do maybe they will raise the priority and address it.  They use the size internally, they simply do not expose it outside as is done with the FILE connector.

2-No, not really.  It gives them back one at a time, not as a list.

3 & 4-It is only loading the entire file into memory if you tell it not to stream or do something else, like an onject-to-string transformer which forces a memory load.  The files or files streams are passed back 1 by 1, but unless you restrict threading and make your flow synchronous, it will go to asych and multi-threaded and process multiple files in parallel.  Flows default to asych, subflow are synchronous.

You can use the SFTP endpoint to retrieve files, and then use a Java or script call to get the file's attributes and filter to only process the files you are actually interested in, such as ones larger than your minimum size.  This would seem more in line with what you are looking for in point 1.  There are other options, but this would be more straight forward that others I can quickly think of.

Answer (score 0):

I found 1 way to get the file size, if we provide transformer-refs="Object_to_Byte_Array" in  and then do #[payload.size()] to get the size of file in Bytes? Will this cause any issue?

Comment: The only issue real that jumps out at me is in my environment I have to access very large files. Doing the Object_to_Byte_Array loads the entire file into memory. If you are dealing with multiple files of Gig and larger files as I do, this breaking of streaming model is an issue. As long as you are only dealing with reasonable sized files, that should not be an issue for you. You then can filter on your size().

Comment: Will that cause any issue with max 20 MB files?

Comment: I would not really think so, but it would depend on how many files you may run simultaneously, how much total memory you have available, other apps that are using that memory, etc.  It is just something to keep in mind and watch for.  In my case, 16 files in the 200MB to 900MB range with 8 GB total available memory is a failure.  20 MB would have worked fine.